# Slang for impossible

Tags: idioms

What kind of slang word or you can say idiom can I use for something that is impossible.

Like we use cherry on the top... Something like that

Here the sentence is "His parents never loved each other and loving him was like......."

Comment: The expression "snowball's chance in hell" comes to mind, i.e., "His parents never loved each other, and loving him was like a snowball's chance in hell." Another is "getting blood from a turnip," i.e., "His parents never loved each other, and loving him was like getting blood from a turnip."  I should say that the sentence doesn't make a lot of sense as it employs a non sequitur. While it's not clear who is doing the loving, his parents or someone else, their not loving him wouldn't effect their ability to love him--maybe his own ability to love, but not theirs.

Comment: And when we read it with the paragraph! It is making sense. You wanna read??

Answer (score 0):

Idiom: **out of the question**

> ***totally unlikely*** or ***not possible***
>
> > Asking my father for money was completely out of the question.
> >
> > Wearing a stained blouse to dinner was out of the question.

`"His parents never loved each other and loving him was like` ***out of the question.***"

Answer (score 0):

**cockamamie** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cockamamie)

> ridiculous; inconceivable.

As in:

> "His parents never loved each other, and trying to love him was
>   cockamamie!"